# I have accidentally put ransomware protection on my C drive

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender, ransomware

I have enabled ransomware protection but accidentally put c drive in my protected folder now it is not letting me change any settings neither is it letting me disabling the setting. Help

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a [Basic Customer Support question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed. You can also contact the developer for assistance with their product.

Comment: Can you disable it via powershell (`Set-MpPreference -EnableControlledFolderAccess Disabled`)?  See this tutorial: [How to Enable or Disable Windows Defender Exploit Guard Controlled Folder Access in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/113380-enable-disable-controlled-folder-access-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: @Tetsujin Ransomware protection is a new feature of Windows 10. How is this a customer support question?

Comment: @LPChip - sorry, that was something I was never going to be able to guess. I was totally unaware, even though I do have one Win10 machine it's never mentioned anything like that to me.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, I didn't know it existed either until I found it by accident. It is part of the niew Windows Security Suite, as a link all the way on the bottom. What it does is prevent any app from modifying files in a given folder.

Comment: @Dhiman Dutta, you should be able to simply turn it off from the settings the same way you turned it on. If that doesn't work, please edit the question and provide details of what you get instead. Do you get an error message, if so, what is the error message?

Comment: I have tried disabling again but the problem is that the protection is blocking literally everything, even settingsui.exe and taskmgr.exe. I am totally in a complicated situation. I can't even revert back to the original settings because it is also blocking those as well so I can't use restore point.

Comment: I can't even factory reset because that is also blocked. Do I have to change my whole c drive and again install windows? If I do this then will the settings become changed to default?

Comment: 1. Run as Administrator 2 . See https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/113380-enable-disable-controlled-folder-access-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Whenever I am trying to run as administration it opens a promt asking me whether I want to give permission to it so that it can make changes to the computer. It is also blocking it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally was able to disable the feature. It was that the system was glitching out so after shutting the system for long time then again starting it I the first notification I got is from windows defender and so I clicked it so directed me to the place where the feature is and I simply disabled it.